# Registering a website with "YouTube" in the name

Tags: domains, legal, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the line drawn with domain names which include a trademark?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9540/where-is-the-line-drawn-with-domain-names-which-include-a-trademark)

Are there legal (or other) issues with registering a site with "YouTube" in the name? An example would be "http://www.youtubepuppies.com". I would be running essentially a blog about puppies (going with this example), writing about how awesome dogs are and posting occasional youtube clips.

This question isn't restricted to "YouTube", that's just an example of a well-known brand. I'm not going to be making any money from the site, nor am I envisioning the site to have a following (beyond what a little personal blog gets).

And I just found a similar question:  [Where is the line drawn with domain names which include a trademark?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9540/where-is-the-line-drawn-with-domain-names-which-include-a-trademark)

Is there a way for a little guy to get "permission" from the brand holder to make a site like this?